# How to use OR inside a term in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch and I need help with adding an `OR` condition in my query. I current have this query.

```
{
  :query=>{
    :bool=>{
      :must=>[{
        :query_string=>{
          :default_operator=>"AND", 
          :query=>"*"
        }
      }]
    }
  }, 
  :filter=>{
    :and=>[{
      :term=>{
        :partner_id=>26
      }
    }, 
    {:term=>{
      :is_unpublished=>"false"}
    }]
  }
}
```

For now, it currently accepts `26` but what if I have 2 values? Eg. 26 and 36, how can I add `36` in OR condition?

If this is SQL it will be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (partner_id = 26 OR partner_id = 36) AND is_unpublished = false
```

I have tried the following but no luck:

```
{:term => {:partner_id => 36}, :or => [:term => {:partner_id => 26}]}
```

Also this no luck:

```
{:term => {:or =>[{:partner_id => 26},{:partner_id => 36}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ‘should’ ?

```
 "should" : [
    { "term" : { "tag" : "wow" } },
    { "term" : { "tag" : "elasticsearch" } }
  ]
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Comment: `should` did not work with me. But with this same piece of code changing `should` to `or` does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Think about [should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html) as an `OR` operator, wrapped by the `query bool` map:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "company" : "stackoverflow" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "parner.is_published" : 1 }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "partner.age" : 26 } },
        { "term" : { "partner.age" : 36 } }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1
    }
  }
}
```

`minimum_should_match` is key to understand, is how many conditions within the `OR` you want elasticsearch to match with.

Also, this is not part of the solution but I think would be relevant to you, if you feel thinking yet on SQL ways, take a look to the [ES SQL style](https://www.elastic.co/products/stack/elasticsearch-sql).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following code.

```
 "should" : [
    { "term" : {
                 "fields": ["tag"],
                 "query: "wow OR elasticsearch" 
              } 
    }
  ]
```